# Add, subtract, multiply, divide etc, lists that are coordinate pairs e.g. time histories

Tags: list-manipulation

I often do signal processing and  have lists that may be time series or spectra that are in the form of

$$ \{ \{x1,y1\},\{x2,y2\}, \{x3,y3\}...\} $$

I usually have lists with all the same x values and want to do operations like adding, subtracting, multiplying etc, corresponding y values. The "proper" way of doing this is to strip of the x values and then operate on the y values and afterwards put the x values back. However, this is tedious and I have developed the following short cut to avoid stripping off the x values.

Here are some example lists and a plot of what they look like:

```
a = Table[{x, BesselJ[0, x]}, {x, 0, 30, 0.2}];
b = Table[{x, 
    E^(-0.2 (x - 0.017 x^2)) Cos[0.14 2 π ( x + 0.004 x^2)]},
   {x, 0, 30, 0.2}];
ListLinePlot[{a, b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code I use to do simple operations, and an example, is

```
 ClearAll[arith];
arith[exp_, a_] := Transpose[{a[[All, 1]], exp[[All, 2]]}]

ListLinePlot[{a, b, arith[a - b, a]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the code `arith` I let the x values be wrecked while working on the y values and then replace the x values in the final output using the second parameter.  This works well and can get satisfactorily complicated which is most useful:

```
ListLinePlot[{a, b, arith[5 (a - b)/(a + b + 10), a]}]

ListLinePlot[{a, b,
  arith[
   z = a + b + 2 + 3 I;
   z Conjugate[z] - 15,
   a]}]
```

[image]

[image]

However, it will not work if the x and y values get mixed or if a number is added that has an inappropriate x value. For example a common operation is

```
arith[a - Mean[a], a]
```

This does not work because `Mean` correctly takes the mean of the x and y values and now there is a list with wrong abscissae. To help me cope with this case I changed `arith` to

```
ClearAll[arith];
SetAttributes[arith, HoldAll];
arith[exp_, a_] := Module[{e1, e},
  e1 = Hold[exp] /. {
     Mean[e_] :> Mean[e[[All, 2]]],
     StandardDeviation[e_] :> StandardDeviation[e[[All, 2]]]
     }
  ;
  Transpose[{a[[All, 1]], ReleaseHold[e1][[All, 2]]}]
  ]
```

The `HoldAll` gives me a chance to work on `Mean` and `StandardDeviation`. Thus  I can now do:

```
 ListLinePlot[{a,
  arith[a - Mean[a], a],
  arith[(a - Mean[a])/StandardDeviation[a], a]}]
```

[image]

However, I am now thinking that this is not the way to go but I should strip off all the x values and then do the operations. I tried to identify lists in the `Held` expression but failed. Can anyone suggest a way forward?  Thanks

Comment: Just to check: `a` and `b` are always guaranteed to have the same set of abscissas, but not necessarily in the same order?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, `a` and `b` and sometimes `c`, `d` and more all have the same abscissas.  I don't catch the `not in the same order` point. The abscissas are in the same order for each list.  It would be an extension to have different orders, although come to think of it I sometimes `Reverse` time histories and then combine them.

Comment: By "not in the same order", I meant that you might consider sets like `a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}` and `b = {{x1, f1}, {x3, f2}, {x2, f3}}`. I guess you don't need to worry about those? (Otherwise, that would complicate possibly straightforward approaches.)

Comment: Anyway: a hacky way would be to temporarily convert your point list to an association, so that you can operate accordingly, e.g. `KeyValueMap[List, Association[Rule @@@ a] + Association[Rule @@@ b]]` and `With[{at = Association[Rule @@@ a]}, KeyValueMap[List, at - Mean[at]]]`. I do find the concept of inexact numbers as keys a little iffy, tho.

Comment: What's wrong with doing [arithmetic](https://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpcnxgi-b60ex8) with `TimeSeries` object itself?

Comment: @swish Thanks, I had considered this but sometimes I have spectra and or lists other than time series. Also, I am often using `Part` and this does not work with `TimesSeries`.

Comment: @Hugh But you can always go back and forth from lists to `TimeSeries` or `EventSeries` if it's more appropriate, depending on what operations you want to do. And `TimeSeriesWindow` may act as an analogue of `Part` for `TimeSeries`.

Comment: @swish You are correct that the `TimeSeries` or `EventSeries` has some useful functions. However, if you wish to minimise the keystrokes keeping closer to the raw data is better. Consider using `Nearest` when looking for the  index number of a frequency in a spectra. I think the real advantage of `TimeSeries` is when you are using date constructs for the time or similar. As I said I considered using `TimeSeries` but think it adds complexity to my sort of signal processing. Each to his own.